# How to package a repository using maven. No java source files included

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, nexus

I'm new to maven. I have a repository contains Ansible playbooks and its config and inventory files. All I want to do is, using Jenkinsfile, SCM Checkout and upload the ansible artifacts to nexus with version increment.
I was able package a war file and upload to nexus. But, when I unzip the war file it contains only below files.

---

```
   98  07-07-2021 16:53   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    0  07-07-2021 16:53   META-INF/
  802  07-07-2021 16:53   META-INF/maven/devansible/AB-ANSIBLE/pom.xml
   86  07-07-2021 16:53   META-INF/maven/devansible/AB-ANSIBLE/pom.properties
```

Now I know Its not working, How can I just package a repository/folder to rar, war or tar anything using maven.
pom.xml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>devansible</groupId>
  <artifactId>AB-ANSIBLE</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Use this to include a selection of jars that will be included in the WAR -->
          <packagingIncludes>${basedir}/*</packagingIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have a look at the assembly plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html

Comment: And since you are on war. Look into this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html. Compare if the directory structure created is correct. Maybe it's src/main/ directory issue.

Comment: Deploying ansible playbooks, roles and inventories using maven to package a war file ?!?!? You are using a saw to drive a screw. Why don't you get those files out of git directly using a tags for your version ? If you use gitlab or github, you can also publish releases based on those tags. Roles can be deployed from their own git repo if needed using a `requirements.yml` file and downloaded through the `ansible-galaxy` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible files are not java files so you should use a packaging for java applications. You can use a jar file to store files, but this is not done for this purpose. I agree, a jar file can contain javadoc files ou java sources but this is still "java world".

From my point of view, the best is to create a "zip" file using the assembly publin [see](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

The other question is: where to store ansible scripts in a maven project?

Looking to [the maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) one solution is to store them in src/main/resources for the applications and in src/test/resources for tests.